# Can a route begin with a variable?

Tags: url-routing, servicestack

This DTO

```cs
[Route("/{Module}/{Name}")]
public class ViewEntityList {
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

causes my app to error on startup with

> RestPath '/{Module}/{Name}' on Type 'ViewEntityList' is not Valid

I could change the route to begin with a literal (e.g. `/Entity/{Module}/{Name}`) but it's not what I want; besides, my URLs are starting to look excessively long and un-REST-like.

Is it possible to begin a route with a variable? If not, is there another way to map any route with two parts to a specific DTO?

Comment: RouteAttribute from which project? I've found several projects that have a RouteAttribute class for doing the kind of thing you're talking about, but there's nothing built into MVC that I'm aware of. There's Tim McCall's attribute routing. There's the one that Stack Exchange uses. And there are others.

Comment: @Pete: This is specific to ServiceStack.

Answer (score 0):

I always do following:

```
        //Configure User Defined REST Paths
        Routes
            .Add<DTO1>("/service/function/{argument}")
            .Add<DTO2>("/service/commonsegment/{Function*}")
```

the mapping for DT1 is the "basic" mapping, one URL correspond to a DTO.

in DTO2 you will need a key called "Function" that will give you the name of the first "non-common" segment of the URL, any other segments preset in the URL will be mapped to your DTO2 if possible (if there is a matching property on it). This way you're open to new functions/arguments without changing the web server itself, only the backing implementation (that could/shlould be located on a external dll).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see how this addresses the question.